# What is the correct translation of "is only suitable for" in French?

Tags: grammaire, verbes

What is the correct translation of "is only suitable for" in French?

Can it be: `est convient uniquement pour`

?
I found that the verb `convient` means `fit`, such as `fit some body` or an agreement. But `seulement` means `only` in english, but according to my lexicon, `uniquement` means `only` too.

So what is the most correct way to say `is only suitable for` in french?

Comment: Some context will be of help:-)! Can you write down the whole sentence in English ?

Comment: The problem is that these techniques are only suitable for - Le probleme est que ces techniques sont convient uniquement pour

Comment: For whom or for what these techniques are suitable for can really make a difference indeed, consider for instance these [examples](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/suitable/616004).

Comment: to only be suitable for = ne convenir qu'/que...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide some context; even better the whole sentence that you try to convey from English in French. See

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/only+suitable+for.html

For instance:

> The problem is that these techniques are only suitable for a qualitative description.

> Le problème est que ces techniques ne conviennent que pour une description qualitative.

Ne...que (no negation!), uniquement and seulement can be interchangeably used in most cases. But for conveying **if only/not only** one must use seulement.

> Je n'aime que la viande/J'aime seulement la viande/J'aime uniquement la viande.

both convey

> I only like meat

But

> Si seulement j'avais mon portable!

conveys

> If only I had my mobile!

and

> Non seulement elle est arrivée en retard, mais elle voulait aussi parler en premier.

conveys

> Not only did she arrive late, she also wanted to speak first.

So in your case, I would say that the turns

> Le problème est que ces techniques ne conviennent que...

> Le problème est que ces techniques sont seulement/uniquement adaptées à...

and so on, are equivalent. Uniquement appears to my not native ears stronger and more formal though.

Comment: Many sentences translate "only suitable for" to "Uniquement pour", "seulement", "convient uniquement pour", "ne conviennent qu'aux". That's confusing.

Comment: Why "ne conviennent que" ? That means "Not agree to" ?

Comment: if only = sulement? Not only = uniqument?

Comment: So seulement and uniquement means the same thing? But there must be a difference between them?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson See my updated answer. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: Ok! So when I use "uniquement", that means "only" and when I add "ne...uniquement...que" it means...only?

Comment: Did not know that "ne...<verb>...que" means only <verb> :)

Comment: @DanielMårtensson I am happy if my answer was helpful for you. Should you new questions, do not hesitate to open a new thread.

Comment: Yes. It was very helpful! Thank you! Merci beaucoup!